# How to run Laravel artisan on a live server without shell_exec?

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravel-artisan, shell-exec

My new project is based on Laravel framework, and developers need to run `php artisan` commands to do their requirements. On the other hand, server configuration disabled `shell_exec` for security purposes.
What should I do for this case? Is there any secure way for developers considering server security issues?

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to run php artisan command.Below  i have mention all of them :

1) Use Terminal which is on server.Through that you can execute the php artisan command.

2) Use "putty" software to access the server.In that you can connect putty with server.For connection to the server you require "SSH credential" which you can create on server.

3) Using route you can execute artisan command.But for that every time you need to add/modify route and execute that in the browser so that artisan command will execute.Below i have given an example of it.You just have to put it in the routes file:

```
Route::get('command', function () {

    /* php artisan migrate */
    \Artisan::call('migrate');
    dd("Done");
});
```

The above route you need to call through browser.This route will execute command of "`php artisan migrate`".

Comment: Did you pay attention to `shell_exec` issue I had mentioned in the question? Running commands is not the problem.